# Compute Covariance Matrix in Java

Tags: java, math, matrix, linear-algebra, covariance

I want to calculate covariance matrix using Java.

Is there any free library to compute covariance Matrix in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/) library can do this.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a short example, how you can create it with Apache Commons Math (3.5):

```
RealMatrix mx = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(new double[][]{
  {1, 2, 3},
  {2, 4, 6}
});
RealMatrix cov = new Covariance(mx).getCovarianceMatrix();
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use the [Efficient Java Matrix Library](http://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) to calculate it too: https://gist.github.com/nok/73d07cc644a390fad9e9